# Google Drive/Sheets API - Not Granting Permission (Python)

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am having trouble granting access (e.g., edit access as well) to other users.

In my client secret JSON file: I have a compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com that I don't have access to. How can I give permissions to another user?

Steps I've taken:

- I've followed steps in this link: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python
- Enabled the Drive and Sheets API in my Google dev account
- Created a secret JSON
- Successfully created a sheet
- Tried changing the client_email to mine: doesn't work

I'm able to create a sheet through `pprint(response)`:

```
 u'index': 0,
 u'sheetId': 0,
 u'sheetType': u'GRID',
 u'title': u'Sheet1'}}],
 u'spreadsheetId': u'1Iry-ugS94VnMA47IhBiF5GIuJNY7phmkPitrfnk7j6c',
 u'spreadsheetUrl': u'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iry-ugS94VnMA47IhBiF5GIuJNY7phmkPitrfnk7j6c/edit'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you give a little more information on your use case, including whether this is a web app or an installed app, and who owns the spreadsheet,

Comment: Hello it is a web app that I'm trying to run through python on my computer